# Python difference between hasattr and has_attr

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jython, hasattr

Despite the "similarly phrased" warning, I don't think this has been asked.

I'm starting to use BeautifulSoup (v4) and, for example, to get the href from an A-link you might do this:

```
for a_link in soup.html.body.select( 'a' ):
    print( a_link )
    if a_link.has_attr( 'href' ):
        print( a_link[ 'href' ])
    if a_link.has_attr( 'hrefXXX' ):
        print( "... also hrefXXX")
    print( hasattr( a_link, 'href' ) )
    print( hasattr( a_link, 'hrefXXX' ) )
```

... what happens here is that the "also" line is never printed, but that the final 2 lines always return `True`! In fact it appears not to matter what you put as the 2nd argument in `hasattr`, it always seems to return `True`.

Without being able to explain `hasattr`'s  behaviour, my first thought, after trying searching, was that `has_attr` might be very specific to BeautifulSoup. From searching, this does appear to be the case: in other words this is finding whether an HTML tag has a "tag attribute".

On the other hand, I have a slight suspicion that `has_attr` may have wider application than BeautifulSoup. Years ago I used Jython and I have a feeling that there may have been a `has_attr` and a `hasattr`.

Can someone explain why `hasattr` is always returning `True`?

Comment: Are you aware that ``hasattr`` is a Python builtin, whereas ``.has_attr`` is a method specific to BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I was aware that `hasattr` was a builtin, yes. As my question hopefully implies, I wasn't sure about `has_attr`.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of bs4 API. `hasattr()` is always `True`, because you can select tags just with dot syntax (`.`). For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<body>
    <hrefyyy>This is hrefyyy</hrefyyy>
</body>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

body = soup.find('body')

print( hasattr(body, 'hrefxxx' ))  # True
print( hasattr(body, 'hrefyyy' ))  # True

print( body.hrefxxx )     # <--- this is not error, it just returns `None`
print( body.hrefyyy )     # <--- returns <hrefyyy> tag
```

Prints:

```
True
True
None
<hrefyyy>This is hrefyyy</hrefyyy>
```

---

Note:

```
a_link.has_attr( 'hrefXXX' )
```

will try to find all `<hrefXXX>` tags under `<has_attr>` tags, but returns empty `ResultSet`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I honestly don't really understand it: it seems very misleading to return `True` to every `hasattr` call. `soup.html` actually has a `body` "attribute" (in the Python sense, not the "HTML tag" sense). But in your example `body` does not have a `hrefxxx` "attribute".  But I'm a low-level Python person: I'll just have to try and grasp it.